# Admob xml: the following classes could not be instantiated: - com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView

Tags: android, xml, admob, google-play-services, adview

I followed all the steps to import google-play-services, tried re-installing sdk, re-importing. I tried adding weight and text-views to give it space... I tried everything for the past 2 days, but keep getting this error on the graphical interface of the xml layout saying:

```
the following classes could not be instantiated: - com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.
```

*********manifest*/************

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.alphaking.xxxxxxe"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >

        <activity
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name="xxxxxxxxxe.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.STARTINGPOINTS" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name="com.alphaking.ijumprope.Settings"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name="com.alphaking.ijumprope.Start"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name="xxxxxxxxxxxxx.Logs"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name="cxxxxxxxxe.About"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

         <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name="xxxxxxxxxxx.Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

         <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>



    </application>

</manifest>
```

*********////////*************main activity java************************

```
package cxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;

import com.alphxxxxxxgxxxxxxxxxx;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    Button setting,start,logs,about;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

        setting=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        setting.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.Settings");
                    Intent ourIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ourClass);
                    startActivity(ourIntent);
                    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
        });

        start=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.alphaking.ijumprope.Start");
                    Intent ourIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ourClass);
                    startActivity(ourIntent);
                    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
        });

        logs=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        logs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    Class ourClass = Class.forName("cxxxxxxxxxxxx
                    Intent ourIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ourClass);
                    startActivity(ourIntent);
                    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
        });

        about=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        about.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    Class ourClass = Class.forName("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxAbout");
                    Intent ourIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ourClass);
                    startActivity(ourIntent);
                    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
        });


    }
    public void onBackPressed() {
    }


}
```

************************xml************************************

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.alphaking.xxxxxxxxxxxxxActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/start" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/setup" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/logs" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/about" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-1278770925901425/7987430192"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        android:gravity="center" >
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Which version of GPS are you using? BTW ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" isn't supported when using admob via GPS

Comment: r u using Android studio..?

Comment: gms 5.0.89-000, it doesn't even work with the java code given by google

Comment: I have the exact same problem in all my projects with ads when opening xml layouts. Started happening after I updated gps to 19. Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Nope, my app is ad-free!

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have added wrong activity class in your manifest file. So just change it with this.

```
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

Comment: I have already tried this and it does not work, as stated in the answer below

Answer (score 1):

Go to dimens.xml and change layout margin value from 16dp to 0dp.

Answer (score 1):

This is a temporary work-around for me. I downgraded the version of Google Play Services SDK from 5.x back to 4.x. I use Intellij Community 13.x with Gradle so my dependency section looks like this now:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.+'
}
```

Again, just temporary to allow me to finish building my XML layout files. I plan to upgrade to the latest version 5.x when I enter my final testing phase. I have filed issues about this problem with the Google AdMob Ads Developers forum in hopes of getting someone's attention. Not exactly sure where to file a bug report for this specific SDK. .

Answer (score 0):

Declare `com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity` in the manifest,i.e. in your manifest file change

```
 <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView"
               android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

to

```
 <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
                  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

For more info see [Declare com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/)

Also add  `android:id="@+id/adView"` in your xml view as

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-1278770925901425/7987430192"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        android:gravity="center" >
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

And don't forget to clear project.

For more info see [Create your banner in XML](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals)

Comment: still doesn't work, but yeah that is the correct one, I changed it to adview by accident to see if it would work

Comment: @Alphak what do you mean by doesn't work?Did you try to clear your project?

Comment: clear as in clean? I cleaned it, and it still gives me: the following classes could not be instantiated: - com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView. in the XML graphic layout

Comment: still doesn't work, this is all stuff i tried after the original google code, the original google code wasn't working for me.

Comment: @Alphak Are you using google play services library  or admob standalone jar?

Comment: @Alphak also add  `android:id="@+id/adView"` in your xml,see answer.

Comment: didnt work, the google one has it, i already tried google's code, the code i posted is merely another attempt

Comment: remove the line  ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" in xml and check

Comment: I'm guessing it has to do with libraries or something, except everything seems to be fine, java codes regarding the ad stuff are instantiated, just the xml giving problems..

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Open your xml layout, Switch to **Text** view, On the **Preview** pane click the **Refresh** button and the problem will be solved.

If the problem persists, make sure you have the firebase ads dependency in your app's build.gradle file:

> compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.8.0'